# Strange Error Message Submitting from InfoPath to WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, infopath2010

I'm building an InfoPath form (InfoPath 2010) and in Custom Code I'm calling a WCF Service programatically as part of the submit action as below:

DriverHours.DriverHours allHours = new DriverHours.DriverHours();
        bool spec;

```
    XPathNavigator myNav = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();

    string allData = myNav.OuterXml;
    allData = allData.Replace("my:", "");

   result = allHours.SaveDriverHoursByString(allData);
```

SaveDriverHoursByString just takes a string of XML Data, saves it to a database on the backend via WCF.

When the submit block executes, the following error shows up on the last line:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:Xml. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 208, position 21.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at HrsServicetemplate.DriverHours.DriverHours.SaveDriverHoursByString(String Xml)
   at HrsServicetemplate.FormCode.FormEvents_Submit(Object sender, SubmitEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.FormEventsHost.OnSubmit(DocReturnEvent pEvent)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust._XDocumentEventSink2_SinkHelper.OnSubmitRequest(DocReturnEvent pEvent)
```

Now I'm aware that the solution is to increase the content length on the web.config of the WCF Service.  Below is my web.config file now, and the error still occurs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   <!--<add name="IFMS_Connection" connectionString="Data Source=aaaa;User Id=aaaa;Password=abcdefg;"/>    -->
    <add name="IFMS_Connection" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=aaaa)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = ORCLDEVL)));User Id=aaa;Password=aaaa;"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>

        <binding name="NoSecurityBinding"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
             maxDepth="2147483647"
             maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
             maxArrayLength="2147483647"
             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message establishSecurityContext="false"/>
          </security>


        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>



    </bindings>


    <services>

    </services>
    <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />         
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

          <serviceDebug
            includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Any ideas?  In particular I'm wondering about missing config entries, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have updated the configuration on the server side, but not the configuration of the client.